# CCMenuItemLable don't run block or selector

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to use CCMenuItemLabel, but when I press it nothing happens. 
I also have menu item with sprite that works perfectly with about the same code.

Any idea?

```
CCMenuItemLabel *miLabel = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:tmpLabel target:self selector:@selector(doSomethingTest)];

miLabel.tag = tmpTag++;
__block NSString *actionName = [menuItemData objectForKey:kActionName];
[miLabel setBlock:^(id sender) {
      ASLog2Debug(@"[Test]");
      [self handlePressForMenuItemWithActionName:actionName];

}];
```

Comment: Does tmpLabel actually get created successfully?

Comment: miLabel not added to any parent node ?

Comment: The label got created, and the menu item is shown (added).